Why do heavier particles decay more faster or lives shorter? Is it due to the uncertainty principle?
If so, why does larger uncertainty in time imply longer lifetime? How does this link to the smaller uncertainty in energy of the massive particle?

I'm not an expert, but I suspect this is due to the difference in energy between the heavy particle and the final state. The larger the difference, the more unstable the particle.

That is merely a rule of thumb. Something can be heavy and yet metastable, i.e. decays slowly.

Your question is mix of two principles.
One is phase space. Fermi's Golden Rule tells is that the rate of a transition depends on the matrix element coupling the stats times the density of states in the final state. The matrix element is fixed (to first order) it is:
$$ M_{fi} = \langle f|H'| i\rangle $$
that is, the coupling of the initial and final states by the interaction hamiltonian. An example is the weak interaction coupling the neutron to the proton (and other beta decay products).
The density of final states depends on the energy, $E$, available in the transition. Since the final particle momentum:
$$ p = \sqrt{2ME} $$
can go in any direction:
$$\rho(p)dp \propto p^2 dp $$
the amplitude rises quickly with energy. (Note that neutrons are stable in nuclei because $E<0$...the decay amplitude is the still there, but the final state density is zero, so they are stable.)
The other concern has to do with virtual particles. So for instance, if a neutron needed to decay, in terms of old fashioned perturbation theory, it would need to create a $W^+$ boson with energy $M_W \gg (m_n - m_p - m_e)$ (plus a $W^-$ term), and that was unlikely since the boson could only exist for a short period of time because the energy difference is so large. That view, which invokes the HUP, is super common in pop-sci.
In modern (post 1948), the W boson is off-shell, and the amplitude to create the kinematically correct W boson is modulated by the Breit-Wigner resonance formula, and it's just small when the energy is off-resonance ($E = M_W$). The HUP has nothing to do with it.

Heavier does not matter directly. What matters is the amount of extra energy available. When you compute the decay rate, you integrate over the parameter space of all the decay products. The more available energy the more likely the decay is to occur.
